# How to calculate rest of the amount after comparing current date in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: pyspark

I need to calculate how much I have in my account after today. That means, for the current day
how much I left in my original Total_salary.

Below is my sample data set.

```
start_date    end_date    duration(months)   Total_salary   left_amount

2021-05-03    2022-05-03   12                   1200                400
2019-01-01    2023-01-01   48                   4800                2300
2018-01-01    2020-01-01   24                   2400                0
2020-01-01    2023-01-01   36                   3600                1200
2024-01-01    2027-01-01   36                   3600                3600
```

I need get the upto current date how much I left, if end_date < current date.
Let take first row as an example, I agree with a client for working for 12 months with total
salary 1200, by each month I will receive 100 as my salary. So, I need to know today how much
I left from my original total_salary. (100*8 = 800, 1200-800 = 400)
I don't know how to get SUM up to current date.

I need to implement this in pyspark. Please anyone can help me to sort out this?

Thank you

Comment: Could you provide your expected output?

Comment: Ok, I'll modify

Comment: I assume `current_date` is today (2021-01-19)?

Comment: Please I need  current_date for today , tomorow, day after tomorow etc..Not only for today.

Comment: Yes, sure - check my answer below :)

Comment: Thank you, but for tomorrow current_date = current_date = datetime.date(2022, 1, 2). I need not to hard code for this tomorrow. When the programs run it automatically get the current date, I need something like that. Also, pls I need to get the output as it is for the last row ( in my example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import datetime
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

current_date = datetime.date.today()

(
    df
    .withColumn('left_months', F.greatest(F.lit(0), F.months_between('end_date', F.lit(current_date))))
    .withColumn('left_amount', F.col('total_salary')/F.col('duration(months)') * F.col('left_months'))
    .withColumn('left_amount', F.least('total_salary', 'left_amount'))
)
```

Comment: Thank you , and pls can you explain me  F.greatest(F.lit(0), F.months_between('end_date', F.lit(current_date)))  ?

Comment: The `greatest()` call is for the case that the end date is in the past and the `rows_between()` returns a negative value.

Comment: I updated my answer with an additional line the prevents that the left_amount is greater than the total salary

Comment: I want to verify with you, if I need to  re-calculate above reslts for the current month, is it correct to use as :  current_date = datetime.date.today()     current_month = current_date.month ? Please is it corrcet the way?